# Polymer data bind without dom-bind

Tags: dom, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a polymer element `<my-element>` with a computed property `myProperty`. I need to bind `myProperty` to another place in the HTML page, so I can't put it inside a `dom-bind` template

Here's what I mean

```
<html>
   <body>
       <div>
          <my-element my-property="{{myProperty}}"></my-element>
       </div>
       <!--somewhere deep inside another part of the document-->
       <div>
          <h4>myProperty = </h4><span>[[myProperty]]</span>
       <div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I cannot wrap `my-element` and the usage of `[[myProperty]]` in a `dom-bind` template as this would result in nearly the entire document being enclosed in this. Attempting to use the bind as it is results in `myProperty = [[myProperty]]` being displayed, not the value of `[[myProperty]]`.

Is there some way to have behaviour similar to data binding but usable across the whole HTML document? (In the future there might also be a case where `[[myProperty]]` is used inside an attribute such as `<my-second-element my-property="[[myProperty]]">`). Or if both occurences are wrapped individually in `dom-bind` templates is there some way to make the bind global?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you wouldn't be able to do like this:

```
<head>
   ...
   <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
   ...
</head>

<html>
   <body>
       <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
         <div>
           <my-element my-property="{{myProperty}}"></my-element>
         </div>
         <!--somewhere deep inside another part of the document-->
         <div>
           <h4>myProperty = </h4><span>[[myProperty]]</span>
         <div>
       </template>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is totally doable. If `myProperty` changes inside `my-element` it would also change in "this" html-document. There also wouldn't be a problem adding your second element:

```
<my-second-element my-property="[[myProperty]]">
```

Unless you're missing to tell us some specific behavior that you want, this should be what you want. :)

Comment: For the sake of compactness I greatly simplified the structure. The first parent that the `div` tags share contains the rest of a very complex website, the `div`s themselves  would be at least 6 layers of DOM down. The idea of wrapping this much unrelated content seems to defeat the aim of Polymer

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You ask for: "[...] but usable across the whole HTML document". This is exactly what this code accomplishes. If you only want a part of the page, then just wrap that part of the page in `dom-bind`.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I want two parts of the page, one that contains `<my-element>` and one that has the `<span>[[myProperty]]</span>`. The idea being that each part could be anywhere in the document (for example, one part in the navbar and another in the main content section, without having to wrap the entire body in a template)

Comment: I don't see this being possible unless you wrap each of the parts in separate `<template is="dom-bind" id="template1">` and `<template is="dom-bind" id="template2">`. And then you find them in Javascript by their id, and then "manually" when the property `myProperty` of `template1` change, you "forcefully" change the `myProperty` of `template2`. But this is ugly and I don't see why you don't just wrap your whole html-page as an template and start refactoring this huge complex site into smaller components after hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although it is correct it's not perfect for my situation (for complicated reasons) but it helped clear up some misconceptions about data binding for me.